Alternating series with Gaussian weights
I'm wondering if anyone knows anything about approximating alternating series with Gaussian weights, i.e., sums of the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{i+1}e^{-a(i-b)^2},
$$
for positive $a$ and $b$. I know this is connected to the Jacobi theta function when $b=0$, but I'd like to know about the general case.
